# Removing this value from a deeply nested list

Tags: python, json, list, nested-lists

I have the following data structure returned as a JSON object:

```
[[[13,
       u'Arsenal',
       [[6.125,
         [[u'assist', u'cross', [3]],
          [u'normal', u'cross', [198]],
          [u'normal', u'longball', [326]],
          [u'assist', u'short', [5]],
          [u'normal', u'short', [4726]],
          [u'assist', u'throughball', [1]],
          [u'normal', u'throughball', [35]]]]]]]]
```

I am having a problem converting this structure into a dictionary. This dictionary has a set of tuples as the keys, made up from the text objects in the above nested lists (i.e. `('assist', u'cross')`). The code I am using to do this is:

```
for match in responser: 
        for num_events, team, events in match:
            regex = {tuple(sub[:2]): sub[2][0] for y in events[0] for sub in y}
```

However this returns the following error:

```
 exceptions.TypeError: 'float' object is not iterable
```

The reason for this seems to be the value `6.125,`. How can I remove this from my nested list structure, but maintain the same number of brackets to allow the code that converts from nested list to dictionary to keep working?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't iterate over the float, if you look at your variable events:

```
events[0] = [6.125,
 [[u'assist', u'cross', [3]],
  [u'normal', u'cross', [198]],
  [u'normal', u'longball', [326]],
  [u'assist', u'short', [5]],
  [u'normal', u'short', [4726]],
  [u'assist', u'throughball', [1]],
  [u'normal', u'throughball', [35]]]]
```

Notice element 0 = 6.125

change the code to:

```
regex = {tuple(sub[:2]): sub[2][0] for y in events[0][1:] for sub in y}
```

Notice the specification for events -- that will skip element 0 and take all the rest.

output for regex is then:

```
{(u'assist', u'cross'): 3,
 (u'assist', u'short'): 5,
 (u'assist', u'throughball'): 1,
 (u'normal', u'cross'): 198,
 (u'normal', u'longball'): 326,
 (u'normal', u'short'): 4726,
 (u'normal', u'throughball'): 35}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. i've gone for your answer as it is the one that requires the least changes to the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can always change `events` once you're inside the inner loop. This will shorten the required list comprehension for `regex` as well.

```
responser = [[[13,
               u'Arsenal',
               [[6.125,
                 [[u'assist', u'cross', [3]],
                  [u'normal', u'cross', [198]],
                  [u'normal', u'longball', [326]],
                  [u'assist', u'short', [5]],
                  [u'normal', u'short', [4726]],
                  [u'assist', u'throughball', [1]],
                  [u'normal', u'throughball', [35]]]]]]]]

for match in responser: 
    for num_events, team, events in match:
        events = events[0][1]
        regex = {tuple(e[:2]): e[2][0] for e in events}

print regex

### Prints the following.
###{(u'normal', u'short'): 4726, (u'normal', u'cross'): 198, (u'assist', u'short'): 5, (u'normal', u'throughball'): 35, (u'normal', u'longball'): 326, (u'assist', u'throughball'): 1, (u'assist', u'cross'): 3}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't the most elegant solution, I'm sure, but I like this problem so I decided to have some fun with it... This function recursively removes all floats from nested, iterable containers:

```
def removeFloat(container):
    if hasattr(container, '__iter__'):
        elementsToRemove = []
        for item in container:
            if isinstance(item, float):
                elementsToRemove.append(item)
        for item in elementsToRemove:
            container.remove(item)

        for item in container:
            removeFloat(item)
```

[Working Ideone example here](http://ideone.com/iq3SMO)

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. this is an interesting piece of code that I will no doubt prove useful in future projects.

Comment: @user3045351 No trouble! Just make sure you don't remove the elements from the container as you're iterating over it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can change events[0][1] for events[0]. Also, you don't want to iterate inside each y:

```
In [31]: for match in responser: 
            for num_events, team, events in match:
                    print {tuple(y[:2]): y[2][0] for y in events[0][1]}
   ....:         
{(u'normal', u'short'): 4726, (u'normal', u'cross'): 198, (u'assist', u'short'): 5, (u'normal', u'throughball'): 35, (u'normal', u'longball'): 326, (u'assist', u'throughball'): 1, (u'assist', u'cross'): 3}
```